# Conditional dependent parameter type

Tags: typescript

I have a snippet

```
interface IProps {
  isEdit: boolean;
  menuOpenId: number | boolean
}

function useMenuForm({ isEdit, menuOpenId }: IProps){...}
```

How can I achieve `menuOpenId` to be `number` if `isEdit` is `true` otherwise its a boolean

Answer (score 0):

You can separate out the interfaces with the help of [boolean literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/literal-types.html#boolean-literal-types), and then use the union type to type `IProps`.

```
interface IPropTrue {
  isEdit: true;
  menuOpenId: number
}

interface IPropFalse {
  isEdit: false;
  menuOpenId: boolean
}

type IProps = IPropTrue | IPropFalse
```

Comment: I tried this and TS gave me error `Argument of type '{ isEdit: boolean; menuOpenId: number | boolean; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'IPropTruthy | IPropFalsy'.` From where the function is being called